# How to pass optional parameter LocalTime in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, datetime, kotlin, localtime

I want to pass a optional parameter in my function which uses a LocalTime data. But LocalTime just accept formatted values. How can I pass a null or default value to it?

```
data class OpeningHours(
        var startServiceHours: LocalTime,
        var finalServiceHours: LocalTime,
        var inconvenienceStartTime: LocalTime?,
        var inconvenienceFinalTime: LocalTime?
) {
    fun contains(time: LocalTime): Boolean {
        return if (startServiceHours.isAfter(finalServiceHours))
            (time.isAfter(startServiceHours) || time.isBefore(finalServiceHours)) &&
                    containsInconvenience(time)
        else
            (time.isAfter(startServiceHours) && time.isBefore(finalServiceHours)) &&
                    (time.isBefore(inconvenienceFinalTime) && time.isBefore(inconvenienceStartTime))
    }

    private fun containsInconvenience(time: LocalTime): Boolean {
        return if (inconvenienceFinalTime?.isAfter(inconvenienceStartTime)!!)
            time.isAfter(inconvenienceFinalTime) || time.isBefore(inconvenienceStartTime)
        else
            time.isAfter(inconvenienceFinalTime) && time.isBefore(inconvenienceStartTime)
    }
}
```

I can't use a "00:00:00" default value, for example, because I need for each date. Need to be literally a default value.

Comment: You can use (time: LocalTime?) and inside method add this line: val currentTime = time ?: LocalTime(), and after use currentTime instead time

Comment: You can make the argument be a default value if you don't have anything to pass, like `fun contains(time: LocalTime = LocalTime.MIN): Boolean`, for example. Then you can invoke the method without the argument.

Answer (score 0):

To pass null to this function, just add `?` on dataType, which indicates dataType is nullable and you can pass null if you want.
modify your function like

```
 private fun containsInconvenience(time: LocalTime?): Boolean {
        return if (inconvenienceFinalTime?.isAfter(inconvenienceStartTime)!!)
            time.isAfter(inconvenienceFinalTime) || time.isBefore(inconvenienceStartTime)
        else
            time.isAfter(inconvenienceFinalTime) && time.isBefore(inconvenienceStartTime)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An optional parameter could be passed to your `fun` by defining it directly in the signature:

```kotlin
data class OpeningHours(
        var startServiceHours: LocalTime,
        var finalServiceHours: LocalTime,
        var inconvenienceStartTime: LocalTime?,
        var inconvenienceFinalTime: LocalTime?
) {
    // parameter defined with a default value here
    fun contains(time: LocalTime = LocalTime.MIN): Boolean {
        return if (startServiceHours.isAfter(finalServiceHours))
            (time.isAfter(startServiceHours) || time.isBefore(finalServiceHours)) &&
                    containsInconvenience(time)
        else
            (time.isAfter(startServiceHours) && time.isBefore(finalServiceHours)) &&
                    (time.isBefore(inconvenienceFinalTime) && time.isBefore(inconvenienceStartTime))
    }
    
    // parameter defined with a default value here
    private fun containsInconvenience(time: LocalTime = LocalTime.MIN): Boolean {
        return if (inconvenienceFinalTime?.isAfter(inconvenienceStartTime)!!)
            time.isAfter(inconvenienceFinalTime) || time.isBefore(inconvenienceStartTime)
        else
            time.isAfter(inconvenienceFinalTime) && time.isBefore(inconvenienceStartTime)
    }
}
```

`LocalTime.MIN` is equivalent to `00:00:00.0` and will be used if you don't pass anything to that `fun`, like invoking it without parameter: `containsInconvenience()`. But it won't replace a `null` if you make it `containsInconvenience(time: LocalTime? = LocalTime.MIN)`. You would have to take care of that in the body.